# Simplify django init on getting model object

Tags: python, django

I need to modify the way an object is fetched in a django model. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
class GoogleAvail(models.Model):
    platform_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    master_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    instance_data = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) # this is json

    def _post_init(self):
        instance_data = json.loads(self.instance_data)
        for k in instance_data:
            setattr(self, k, instance_data[k])
        return self
```

Now, when I need to get an object I call:

```
>>> a=GoogleAvail.objects.all()[0]
>>> a._post_init()
```

Note that I'm only interested in doing this init when the object is fetched, as it would be unnecessary to do `json.loads()` (with a ton of data) on 10,000 objects in I were to do a model manager on the queryset.

What would be a better way to do this, so it does so automatically, and I don't need to call the `_post_init` ?

Comment: Why you don't overwrite the `__init__() ` method and create the attrs there?

Comment: @trinchet could you please show me how to do that? When I tried overwriting the init method I was getting an error that had to do with executing the `objects` method.

Comment: `def __init__(self):
    super(GoogleAvail).__init__()
    instance_data = json.loads(self.instance_data)
 for k in instance_data:
  setattr(self, k, instance_data[k])
`

Comment: @trinchet right, using that I get: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple options depending on how much refactoring you're willing to do.

- First up if you are (or can easily upgrade) to Postgres, then current versions of django directly support using a [json field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) from there you can convert your queries to `defer()` that field if needed.
- Next option, convert `instance_data` to `_instance_data` and make `instance_data` a `@cached_property` using [django.utils](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property). That will allow you to load it once when you access it from the instance and will cache it automatically for future uses.

Last thing I want to note, be careful with your `_post_init()` because if it's blindly setting values from your json it could easily shadow values that you might want (e.g. what if your json has a field called `save` in it?)